# EJS view will not render when triggered via fetch API

Tags: javascript, express

in my client javascript I am using the following function, which is triggered by an onclick event

```
function submitForm(event) {
const data = { name, image_url };

console.log(data);

fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',         
    },      
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
}
```

The function above sends a post request to the expressJS backend of the app which triggers another function that is supposed to render one of two EJS views. here is the expressJS function

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log('hitting router post');
var { name, imageURL } = req.body;
console.log(name, imageURL);
if (nicknameIsAvailable(name)) {        
    let user = {
        nickname: name,
        id: '',
        image: imageURL,
    };
    console.log("new user connecting")
    res.cookie('nickname', name, { signed: false });
    res.render('chat', { nickname: name });
} else {
    console.log('rejecting user ' + name + ' is already taken');
    res.render('index', { message: userTakenErrorMessage });
}
});
```

problem is that res.render does not actually render the EJS view. I think what is happening is that it's sending back the HTML markup of the view to the client side javascript. The desired behavior would be for it to render the "chat" or "index" views with the given arguments. How can I achieve that?

If this approach does not work then what approach could I use to add some data to the body of a request without using a form and then having that request trigger rendering a view?

Comment: Well, what do mean with "render view"? Your code definitely renders the view, the question is, what do you want to do with the rendered html? Generally, when you send the HTML back to the client (that who make the POST request), it has to somehow process it. So - what should be done with that rendered HTML?
If you want to display some data on another page, maybe use res.redirect(....).

Comment: ...or - you an append the HTML to some div, like element.innerHTML = your data from post request...

Comment: I meant the rendered HTML is not being displayed in the browser. What I want to do with the HTML data is have it display in a new page in the browser and have the arguments that I am passing in the post route available in the browser. My whole point is that, that behavior I just explained occurs when the same method is triggered by an HTML form post. When I try to emulate the same thing via fetch API. the HTML data is sent back as a response and is not displayed in the browser. I want to obtain the same behavior of  submitting a form, without actually having a form

Answer (score 0):

This is an ajax request, you will receive rendered HTML in the resolved promise of fetch function. To display the response content use:

```
fetch(...).then(res => res.text()).then(htmlStr => {
  document.open();
  document.write(htmlStr);
  document.close();
})
```

Comment: ok so form submit is not an ajax request? what kind of request is it then? and how can I emulate the same thing a form request does without using an actual HTML form

Comment: Form submit is not an ajax request. To support Form Submit a request on the server, add express `url-encoded` middleware to the app. Then whatever you will render(send) in response, the browser will refresh and show the content you sent in response.

Comment: that was not the question. The question is "how do I send a form submit with javascript without creating a form" I want to be able to emulate what the browser does when it send a form to the server with client side javascript and wihtout creating an HTML form

Comment: Without form, you won't be able to send post requests.  You have to use either form or ajax. Alternatively, you can set values in the query string and set the page URL to that request. It will send get a request to your server, where you have to get data from the query string. Though this is not good practice to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `fetch()`, and `XMLHttpRequest()` and yes you are right the server sends the data from the page to be render but it actually doesn't render it.
The only thing that worked for me was to use `window.location.href =`  the url of your page " the following example may clarify.

Client side:

```
window.location.href = `booksinfo/${bookId}`
```

Server side:

```
app.get("/booksinfo/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.render("singlebook.ejs")  
});
```